# Capistrano rename a file task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, web-deployment

I am working on an [Opensourced project](https://github.com/vasspilka/LocalGrowth) I want to create, deploying to a VPS.

I'm working with Rails 4 and Capistrano 3 on Ubuntu, both on the local machine and the server.

I have a configuration file named "[application.yml](https://github.com/vasspilka/LocalGrowth/blob/master/config/application.example.yml)" that includes basic information about the application, as a Google Analytics script, the application name, Mailer configurations and such.

I want to create a task that would rename "application.example.yml" to "application.yml" before Capistrano runs `deploy:migrate`.

I wrote the task below and put it in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
before "deploy:migrate", "configure:application"
namespace :configure do 
  task :application do
    run "#{try_sudo} cp #{current_path}/config/application.example.yml #{current_path}/config/application.yml"
  end
end
```

(I know `cp` copies the file but it also renames so it is fine.)

It does not seem to work. How can I rename "application.example.yml" before `deploy:migrate` runs?

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/vasspilka/LocalGrowth) and [deploy.rb](https://github.com/vasspilka/LocalGrowth/blob/master/config/deploy.rb)

Also as I am moving forward with my App I seem to find more and more stuff I know little or nothing about, and would love it if someone experienced with Rails would be willing to become my "Mentor" by sharing with me his Skype (or any other communication service) so I could occasionally ask him my questions.

Comment: In several places in your question you mention "depoly:migrate" but it appears your task is supposed to be called "deploy:migrate". Did you copy the misspellings from somewhere else or mistype them? The difference would definitely cause problems with code.

Comment: Thank you Tin Man, I just mistyped it here nothing to do with my code, edited, now it is written right.

Comment: You seem to have removed a part I would like this question to have, I'll add it again, if it is not allowed on stackoverflow I have no problem to remove it though.

Comment: Asking for mentors is not likely to get responses. I'd recommend using IRC and asking questions on the Ruby and Rails channels. You'll find lots of people who'll give you answers quickly.

Comment: I did not know something like that existed thank you again Tin Man :).